# iframe works for one C-Panel folder but not another

Tags: iframe

I have successfully embeded an iframe in Wordpress (via Elementor) that displays a Unity3D game.  The game is located in c-panel > file manager at: https://wordpress-staging.zafflower.com/SummersDay_020923/index.html.  However, this is a staging site and I would like to have the Unity3D game in a different folder: https://public_html/SummersDay/index.html.  When I copy or move the game to the new folder I get the error message: 'public_html’s server IP address could not be found.'  I have tried changing the permission on the SummersDay folder from 755 to 750 which is the same as the permission on public_html, but that doesn't work.  I have also tried making a new folder outside of public_html and giving it a 750 permission but that doesn't work either.  My Wordpress site is hosted at HostGator.  Is there something that HostGator has to do on their end, or can I do something to fix this?  See iframe code below that works and iframe code that doesn't work.  Any help will be much appreciated.
Zaffer

This iframe works:

```
<iframe src="https://wordpress-staging.zafflower.com/SummersDay_020923/index.html"
width="1200"
height="900"
frameborder="0"
margin="0"></iframe>
```

This iframe doesn't work:

```
<iframe src="https://public_html/SummersDay/index.html"
width="1200"
height="900"
frameborder="0"
margin="0"></iframe>
```

Addumdum: Here is a JPG of the file paths of the two instances of the game.  I am using what I think are the correct paths.

[image]

Comment: We’ll you second example isn’t using a valid URL. You’ve left out the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jacob, I didn't realize that iframe could only reach an address that included a domain, not just a file path.  I solved the problem by creating a subdirectory, games.zafflower.com, and installing a new WordPress site in that subdomain.  Now this iframe code will correctly display my Unity3D game.  Thanks!
Zaffer

```
<iframe src="https://games.zafflower.com/SummersDay/index.html"
width="1200"
height="900"
frameborder="0"
margin="0"></iframe>
```

[image]